How to handle parallel reads/writes with tungstenite's websockets in rust with Mutex
I'm trying to have parallel reading and writing with a websocket. I'm spawning this to listen to connections
tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("Spawning a worker");
        loop {
            let message: Message = {
                let mut locked_socket: MutexGuard<UnifiedWebSocket> = socket.lock().unwrap();
                match locked_socket.read() {
                    Ok(msg: Message) => msg,
                    Err(e: Error) => {
                        eprintln!("Error reading message: {}", e);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            match message {
                Message::Binary(bin: Vec<u8>) => {
                    println!("{:?}", bin);
                    println!("Received a message on websocket");
                }
                _ => continue
            }
        }
    });

Which means that the socket's MutexGuard is constantly locked in a loop.
This means that this part of code that's supposed to write using the socket will stop on the lock step, waiting for the socket to unlock, which will never happen, due to it running in a loop in the snipped above.
#[post("/", format="text", data = "<input>")]
fn my_endpoint(state: &rocket::State<MySharedState>, input: String) -> Status {
    println!("my_endpoint Received a message on endpoint");
    let socket:&mut UnifiedWebSocket = &mut *state.inner().socket.lock().unwrap();

At least that's what I'm suspecting is happening.
I'm not even sure if I've correctly identified the problem and maybe I should handle the socket in different way, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I should also clarify that the UnifiedWebSocket is my shot at unifying the "server" and "client" websocket types with one enum.
enum UnifiedWebSocket {
    Plain(WebSocket<TcpStream>),
    Tls(WebSocket<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>),
}

impl UnifiedWebSocket {
    fn send(&mut self, message: Message) -> Result<(), tungstenite::Error> {
        match self {
            UnifiedWebSocket::Plain(socket) => socket.send(message),
            UnifiedWebSocket::Tls(socket) => socket.send(message),
        }
    }

    fn read(&mut self) -> Result<Message, tungstenite::Error> {
        match self {
            UnifiedWebSocket::Plain(socket) => socket.read(),
            UnifiedWebSocket::Tls(socket) => socket.read(),
        }
    }
}

Here is a minimal reproducible example:
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tungstenite;
use tungstenite::{accept, Message, WebSocket};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

//Logic just to create the socket, we can then connect to with f.eg. postman
fn establishing_example_socket() -> WebSocket<TcpStream> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7777").unwrap();

    loop {
        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            match stream {
                Ok(stream) => {
                    let socket = accept(stream).expect("Error during WebSocket handshake");
                    println!("WebSocket connected successfully");
                    return socket
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Error accepting connection: {:?}", e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//send message is executed before the reading loop so in this example it locks it and never lifts the lock
fn send_message( websocket: Arc<Mutex<WebSocket<TcpStream>>>)
{
    let mut locked_socket = websocket.lock().unwrap();
    println!("Locked for sending");
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        let message = Message::Text("One two".to_owned());
        locked_socket.send(message).unwrap()
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let websocket:Arc<Mutex<WebSocket<TcpStream>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(establishing_example_socket()));
    
    send_message(websocket.clone());

    //We spawn a listener for incoming messages but it can't lock the socket, because it's always locked by the sender
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let mut locked_socket = websocket.lock().unwrap();
            println!("Locked for reading");
            match locked_socket.read() {
                Ok(msg) => {println!("Received: {}", msg)},
                _ => continue
            }
        }
    });
    return;
}

Dependencies for the example:
[dependencies]
tungstenite = "0.21.0"
tokio = { version = "1.37.0", features = ["full"] }


Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. a piece of code we can run and observe the behavior ourselves, with all the necessary imports.

You should not hold the lock for that long. Hold it for the shortest possible period of time. But that still won't solve it, because now the read will be blocking. I suspect the only solution will be to switch to async Rust.

Can I have async listening to websocket whilst the writing will be on a rocket endpoint

Aren't rocket endpoints async anyway?
